# Trying to incorporate Ember into an Express/Bower/Grunt/Node project

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js

I installed Ember and its dependencies through `npm` and `bower`, and included the `ember.js` script in my application, thinking it would do nothing because I hadn't done anything with it yet.

However, it upon refreshing the page, I get 5 console errors with different "Unexpected tokens" and "Ember is not defined".  I also have a huge weird error printed in the markup of my application:

*"Value"===e.childNodes[2].nodeValue}(),o=function(r){var n;n=this instanceof o?this:new e,n.innerHTML=r;var i="metamorph-"+t++;return n.start=i+"-start",n.end=i+"-end",n};e.prototype=o.prototype;var s,l,u,c,h,m,p,f,d;if(c=function(){return this.startTag()+this.innerHTML+this.endTag()},f=function(){return""},d=function(){return""},n)s=function(e,t){var r=document.createRange(),n=document.getElementById(e.start),i=document.getElementById(e.end);return t?(r.setStartBefore(n),r.setEndAfter(i)):(r.setStartAfter(n),r.setEndBefore(i)),r},l=function(e,t){var r=s(this,t);r.deleteContents();var n=r.createContextualFragment(e);r.insertNode(n)},u=function(){var e=s(this,!0);e.deleteContents()},h=function(e){var t=document.createRange();t.setStart(e),t.collapse(!1);var r=t.createContextualFragment(this.outerHTML());e.appendChild(r)},m=function(e){var t=document.createRange(),r=document.getElementById(this.end);t.setStartAfter(r),t.setEndAfter(r);var n=t.createContextualFragment(e);t.insertNode(n)},p=function(e){var t=document.createRange(),r=document.getElementById(this.start);t.setStartAfter(r),t.setEndAfter(r);var n=t.createContextualFragment(e);t.insertNode(n)};el*

How do I even begin troubleshooting this?  What have I done wrong?

**Added ember.js here:**

```
  script(type='text/javascript'): include ../../bower_components/ember/ember.min.js
  script(type='text/javascript'): include ../../bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.min.js
  script(type='text/javascript'): include ../../bower_components/d3/d3.min.js
  script(type='text/javascript'): include ../../bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.min.js
  script(type='text/javascript'): include ../../bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js
  script(type='text/javascript'): include ../../bower_components/ember-charts/dist/ember-charts.js
```

Comment: this doesn't appear to be an error; rather, this is the minified contents of a script file.  Perhaps your `<script />` block is not defined correctly? posting a sample of your HTML document where you added ember.js would help.

Comment: what file is that in?

Comment: it's in a head.jade file that is included in the main jade layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jade, you use `script(src=)` syntax to create a link to an external document.  the `include` keyword would be used when you want to insert the contents of one file into another.

try changing your script lines to:

```
script(type='text/javascript' src='../../bower_components/ember/ember.min.js')
```

Comment: with your original jade file, if you did view -> source, you would see the contents of the .js files actually inline inside the HTML, and not inside a script tag.... it would cause the browser to output the scripts as text.